# How do you query DynamoDb based on Filter for multiple attributes?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table in dynamodb with following attributes 
id -> hashkey
eventname->rangekey
startdate
enddate
locationname
locationtype
cost

I want to query db based on 4 values eventname, locationname, startdate and enddate. 
What can be the best way to do it ?
If I create a GSA then I can only do it based on two attributes

Comment: can you give examples for your queries?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar problems as well. In many cases, it can be helpful to construct combined keys. For example, you could create a GSA with partition key "EVENT+LOCATION" and range key "START-END".

If this doesn't help, can you specify your queries in greater details and give an example?

Cheers,
Fabian